# How to be sure that only one record is taken into account at a given stage of the query?

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl, progress-db

I wonder how exactly the "queries" for each and first work.

lets say I have some tables A, B, C and D.

How many records will I find if I use sth like:

```
first B,
each C,
first D:
<block>
end.
```

`1*|C|*1`? [assuming there will be C that has some relation with B, etc]

And then I have sth like this:

```
for each A,
first B,
/*-----------------------*/
each C,
first D:
<block>
end.
```

How can I make sure to have the same complexity after this change? (B has now relation with A and there will be some where statements) Will it be `|A|*1*|C|*1`? And If I want to have the same complexity as before is there anything I can add there?

---

Example of the problem

```
define temp-table ttA no-undo
    field mainID as character format "x(20)"
    field foreignKey as character format "x(20)"
    index idx_mainID is unique primary mainID
.

define temp-table ttB no-undo
    field mainID as character format "x(20)"
    field foreignKey as character format "x(20)"
    index idx_mainID is unique primary mainID
.

define temp-table ttC no-undo
    field mainID as character format "x(20)"
    field foreignKey as character format "x(20)"
    index idx_mainID is unique primary mainID
.

define temp-table ttD no-undo
    field mainID as character format "x(20)"
    field foreignKey as character format "x(20)"
    index idx_mainID is unique primary mainID
.

DEFINE VARIABLE viCounterA as integer no-undo.
DEFINE VARIABLE viCounterB as integer no-undo.
DEFINE VARIABLE viCounterC as integer no-undo.
DEFINE VARIABLE viCounterD as integer no-undo.
DEFINE VARIABLE viTotal as integer no-undo.
DEFINE VARIABLE viTotal2 as integer no-undo.

assign
    viCounterA = 0
    viCounterB = 0
    viCounterC = 0
    viCounterD = 0
    viTotal = 0
    viTotal2 = 0
    .

DEFINE VARIABLE vcAID as character no-undo.
DO viCounterA = 1 TO 9:
    vcAID = "A0" + STRING(viCounterA).
    create ttA.
    ttA.mainID = vcAID.
    ttA.foreignKey = "".


    DEFINE VARIABLE vcBID as character no-undo.
    DO viCounterB = 1 TO 9:
        vcBID = vcAID + "B0" + STRING(viCounterB).
        create ttB.
        ttB.mainID = vcBID.
        ttB.foreignKey = vcAID.
            
        DEFINE VARIABLE vcCID as character no-undo.
        DO viCounterC = 1 TO 9:
            vcCID = vcBID + "C0" + STRING(viCounterC).
            create ttC.
            ttC.mainID = vcCID.
            ttC.foreignKey = vcBID.

            DEFINE VARIABLE vcDID as character no-undo.
            DO viCounterD = 1 TO 9:
                vcDID = vcCID + "D0" + STRING(viCounterD).
                create ttD.
                ttD.mainID = vcDID.
                ttD.foreignKey = vcCID.
                
            END.
        END.
    END.
END.

/* DISPLAY V1 */
for first ttB,
        each ttC where ttC.foreignKey = ttB.mainID,
            first ttD where ttD.foreignKey = ttC.mainID:
    viTotal = viTotal + 1.
    display
        viTotal
        ttD.mainID
        .
end.

/* DISPLAY V2 */
for each ttA where ttA.mainID = "A01" or ttA.mainID = "A03",
    first ttB where ttB.foreignKey = ttA.mainID,
        each ttC where ttC.foreignKey = ttB.mainID,
            first ttD where ttD.foreignKey = ttC.mainID:
    viTotal2 = viTotal2 + 1.
    display
        viTotal2
        ttD.mainID
        .
end.

display 
    viTotal
    viTotal2
    .
```

Answer (score 1):

It will be the same as:

```
define variable i as integer no-undo.
define variable j as integer no-undo.
define variable k as integer no-undo.

for each A no-lock:

  i = i + 1.

  for first B no-lock:

    j = j + 1.

    for each C no-lock where C.something = B.something:

      k = k + 1.

      display i j k.

    end.

  end.

end.
```

Comment: Yes I have created similar example to test it(to experiment).
```
Do you know what can I add/change in the example with "/*-----------------------*/" so that it has the same "execution" as the first one? I need to make some conditioning of B based on A and I need to have the same results as before.

Should I divide it into two for loops and use sth like firstof after first two lines (where the comment is)?

Comment: I'm sorry but I do not understand your question. I think you might be trying too hard to state it as an abstract problem. It would probably make more sense to me if you  restate the question with runnable sample code with real data and real results that illustrate your problem.

Comment: I have added example with simplified code. (real relations between tables in my db are a bit more complex and the conditioning in "for each ttA where ttA.mainID = "A01" or ttA.mainID = "A03"," is more abstract so in general this line will generate 1 to N records which would get multiplied by complexity of the rest of the query and ruin old complexity.

Comment: I would like to have the same results in `/* DISPLAY V2 */` and `/* DISPLAY V1 */ `assuming that I need to use this where statement: "where ttB.foreignKey = ttA.mainID".

Comment: I made a small adjustment (added format "x(20)" for table fields and changed the lines generating IDs on each level so they are simplified[still unique])

Comment: I am sorry. I just realized what I missed. I missed part about using before other conditioning (can-find). The usage of new relation is supposed to do the same however it alters complexity of these queries by multiplying it by number of records from the first for statement.